# Find Last Row in Dataframe: Python pandas module

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to compare a `list` and a `dataframe`. If an `item` in the `list` equals a value from the first column in the `dataframe's row`, I would like to print out that `list's item` with the `dataframe's second column` value after it.

If no `items` in the `list` match any `items` in the `dataframe's` second column, I would like to just print out the `list's item`. I thought a good way to go about this is to iterate through the whole `list` and `dataframe`, and if we get to the last row of the `dataframe` and non of the items match, print out just the `list's item` instead of the `list's item` plus the `dataframe's second column`.

What I need help with is determining the syntax needed to find the last row in the dataframe. Please see my code below.

The dataframe I'm using is `1003 rows X 2 columns`. The row labels are numbers `0-1002`. The column labels are `col1` and `col2`

```
#compare items from List against items from dataframe to find matches
for item in List:
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if item in row['col1']:
            print str(count) + " " + str(item) + " " + str(row['col2'])
            count=count+1

        #if it's the last row in dataframe:
            if item not in row['col1']:
                print str(count) + " " + str(item)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3339965).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#compare items from List against items from dataframe to find matches
for item in List:
    last_idx = df.iloc[-1].name
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if item in row['col1']:
            print str(count) + " " + str(item) + " " + str(row['col2'])
            count=count+1

        if last_idx == idx:
            if item not in row['col1']:
                print str(count) + " " + str(item)
```

---

consider `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(-1, 4),
                  pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('XY'), [2, 5]]),
                  list('ABCD'))

df
```

[image]

***last index***

```
df.iloc[-1].name

('Y', 5)
```

---

***demo***

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    last_idx = df.iloc[-1].name
    if last_idx == idx:
        print(row)

A    12
B    13
C    14
D    15
Name: (Y, 5), dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out I could use the following line to find the last row in the dataframe

```
if count==len(df):
```